# Different results executing in Anonymous Window and in Einstein Bot

Tags: apex, soql, einstein, einstein-chatbot

I have this class:

```
public class Class {    
    public class HandleInput {        
        @InvocableVariable(required=true)        
        public String idAsset;    
    }        
    public class HandleOutput {        
        @InvocableVariable(required=true)        
        public String status;    
    }

    @InvocableMethod    
    public static List<HandleOutput> find(List<HandleInput> inputParameters){        
        String idAsset = inputParameters.get(0).idAsset;                
        String status = [SELECT Status FROM Asset WHERE id =: idAsset];

        List<HandleOutPut> outPuts = new List<HandleOutput>();        

        HandleOutput outPut = new HandleOutput();        
        outPut.statusPreAutorizacao = status;        
        outPuts.add(outPut);                
        return outPuts;    
    }
}
```

When I execute this class in the anonymous window, the result is Success, but when the Einstein Bot executes the class, it gives an error:

```
System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject
```

When I execute in the anonymous window, I execute this script:

```
Class.HandleInput handleInput = new Class.HandleInput();
handleInput.idAsset = X;

List<Class.HandleInput> inputParameters = new List<Class.HandleInput>();
inputParameters.add(handleInput);

List<Class.HandleOutput> outputs = Class.find(inputParameters);
System.debug(outputs.get(0).status);
```

Why the result is different from executing in anonymous and in Einstein Bot?

Comment: looks like a record access issue.  make sure your einstein bot have required permission and access

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem add the "without sharing" keyword to my class.